# Retaining multiple strings in sed substitution

Tags: sed

**Input:**

```
These are some numbers aklö0/4:asfasd;assdf...asf8/8asdfklöjsdfv7/7asdf8/6 sdf 5/5 asdfasdf3/3 asdf 2/2 asdf7/7asfasdf:::::::7/6;;;;;;6/6asdf9/9......alright
```

**sed Command** applied on the above input:

```
sed 's/\(.\/.\).*\(.\/.\).*\(.\/.\).*\(.\/.\).*\(.\/.\).*\(.\/.\).*\(.\/.\).*\(.\/.\).*\(.\/.\).*\(.\/.\).*\(.\/.\).*/\1\t\2\t\3\t\4\t\5\t\6\t\7\t\8\t\9\t\10\t\11/g' infile > outfile
```

**Expected Ouput:**

```
These are some numbers 0/4 8/8 7/7 8/6 5/5 3/3 2/2 7/7 7/6 6/6 9/9 alright
```

**Problem Encountered :**
but it replaces the last two with 0/40 and 8/81.
It is like it can only remember 9 things.

Comment: Use multiple substitution commands if you want more than 9 backreferences.

Comment: ´sed 's/\(.\/.\).*\(.\/.\)/\1\2/g'´ gives me this: ´these are some numbers 0/09/9 alright´ so I lost everything before next substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. See [The s Command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command):

> The replacement can contain \n (n being a number from 1 to 9,
>   inclusive) references, which refer to the portion of the match which
>   is contained between the nth ( and its matching ). Also, the
>   replacement can contain unescaped & characters which reference the
>   whole matched portion of the pattern space. Finally, as a GNU sed
>   extension, you can include a special sequence made of a backslash and
>   one of the letters L, l, U, u, or E.